# Formatting the time stored in a database with 'now()'

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

I am storing the time a row was created with `now()` in my database, type DATETIME.
If i just read out the field where it was stored, it returns `2017-04-09 10:34:31`.
I'm trying to format it like this: `date('H:i d F Y', $row->created)`
("$row->created" is the database field where my time is stored, it is correct.)
This outputs: `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 52`.
So do i need to format the time differently?
Do i need to store via a different time-outputting function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
date('H:i d F Y', $row->created)
```

try this:

```
date('H:i d F Y', strtotime( $row->created ));
```

**Explanation:** The data returned by mysql query is of string type so you have to change it to suitable type and then convert its format of your choice.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Can you ellaborate? Is it still stored as a string, even though the 'created' column has the type 'DATETIME'? Is 'DATETIME' here just a label, and doesnt actually mean anything?

Comment: For any other help give me your skype id?